# Lightweight convention based MVVM frameworks, are there any?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been looking for a nice convention based MVVM framework, I've looked at [NakedMVVM](http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2010/11/07/naked-mvvm-simplest-possible-mvvm-approach.aspx#comments), which seems to be along the lines of what I'm after.

But can there really be only one? What other options are available?

Comment: @Will why not explain yourself rather than being arbitrary and voiceless?

Comment: Sorry, hit the wrong reason.  We discourage questions that ask for links, as they rot and attract spam.  Also, [Meta] is always a good place to go when you've got a question or a complaint about the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just started using [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) and I've found it very impressive. It is incredibly lightweight (under 3,000 lines of code in all), but includes some features that really simplify common MVVM tasks.

For a complete breakdown of just about every MVVM framework, check [this](http://www.japf.fr/silverlight/mvvm/index.html) out. It's a Silverlight app that lists all of the well-known frameworks and compares them side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie, Caliburn.Micro does look interesting, I wanted something that just did MVVM. However at this stage I'm happy to take a decent look at anything that prefers convention over configuration. Also, that list is great, there's a lot of MVVM frameworks here that I'd never heard of.